# Alerta en Swicth Case en php

Tags: php, html, poo

Quiero poder mostrar un alerta que diga que por favor seleccione un opción cuando no se haya seleccionado ninguna opción de radio. el código que tengo de prueba es el siguiente.

**calculo.php**

```
class Calculadora{
    public function calcular($n1, $n2, $operador)
    {   
        $ope = $_POST['operador'];
        switch ($ope) {
            case 0:
                return $n1 + $n2;
                break;
            case 1:
                return $n1 - $n2;
                break;
            case 2:
                return $n1 * $n2;
                break;
            case 3:
                return $n1 / $n2;
                break;
            default:
                echo "<script>alert('Seleccione una opción');</script>";
                break;
        }
    return $res;
    }
}
    <?php require_once "calculo.php"; 
          $calculadora = new Calculadora();

          $num1 = $_POST['numero_1'];
          $num2 = $_POST['numero_2'];
          $operador = $_POST['operador'];
          $operacion = array('suma', 'resta', 'multiplicacion', 'division');

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" action="" name="form1">
    <input type="number" name="numero_1" required>
    <input type="number" name="numero_2" required>
    <input type="radio" name="operador" value="0">
    <input type="radio" name="operador" value="1">
    <input type="radio" name="operador" value="2">
    <input type="radio" name="operador" value="3">
    <input id="boton" type="submit" value="Resultado">
    <?php echo "El resultado de la ".$operacion[$operador]." es:".$calculadora->calcular($num1, $num2, $operador);?>
</form>
```

Comment: Podrías validarlo con javascript o mas fácil aun ten seleccionado uno por defecto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sustituye esta línea

```
$ope = $_POST['operador'];
```

Por:

```
$ope = isset($_POST['operador']) ? $_POST['operador'] : -1;
```

Con esto evitarás un error cuando el formulario no envie el valor del operador al dejar sin seleccionar los radios. Y al asignarle un valor a $ope cuando sucede esto caerá en tu **default** del switch